# how to get an image from HTML page Android studio

Tags: android, url, jpeg

I have an image in JPG in a sit (I suppose it is HTML format but I am not sure about it). I open the source of the page and I see there the image I need written this way. 
If I take the link it show me the image.
But i don't know how can I get from the URL page to get this link. It is not look like written in JSON format.
How can I get it?
Thanks
Bar.

Comment: Well show how it looks. Do we have to guess?

Comment: By mistake I didn't copy the text:

Comment: It is look like this <meta property="og:image" content="http://optichouse.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/מבצע-ספטמבר-2015.jpg" /> It is notlook like a regulare JSON format. So how can I dig to get the jpg link?

Comment: Why are you talking about json the whole time? You have a html page with a meta tag. You need to parse out the content attribute of a meta tag. Parse it out yourself or look for a suitable html parser.

Comment: Because I only use JSON when I get data from URL sit. Do you have any example of HTML parser that can do this job?

Comment: I just find this tutorial http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2014/04/parsing-html-in-android-with-jsoup.html and this one http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax but in my case I don't know what is the elements and what I should put as selector . I want to get the link end with the .jpg written in the mata data like this <meta property="og:image" content="http://optichouse.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/מבצע-ספטמבר-2015.jpg" /> So does the meta is the element and the og:Image is the select or the og:Image is the element and the content is the select?

Comment: Well just try them all and look at some examples.

Answer (score 1):

After some play I get to this:
The meta is the elements, and og.image and content are one of there meta data attribute.
So I do as follow to get the image URL string
        String imageLink=null;
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "Connecting to [" + strings[0] + "]");
            Document doc  = Jsoup.connect(strings[0]).get(); // put all the HTML page in Document

```
        // Get meta info
        Elements metaElems = doc.select("meta");

        for (Element metaElem : metaElems) {
            String property = metaElem.attr("property");
            if(property.equals("og:image"))// if find the line with the image
            {
                imageLink = metaElem.attr("content");
                Log.d(TAG, "Image URL" + imageLink );
            }


        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        exception =e;
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Very good that you found it yourself. You would not have wanted me to tell you all this ? ;-).

Answer (score 0):

Here I am posting the small code snippet for ingrate this kind of functionality may this help you.

**Step 1:** Add below gradle

```
compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.2'
```

**Step 2:**
Use below async task for get all meta information from any Url.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ImageView imgOgImage;
private TextView text;
String URL = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ufaK_Hd6BpI";
String UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    imgOgImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgOgImage);
    new FetchMetadataFromURL().execute();

}

private class FetchMetadataFromURL extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    String websiteTitle, websiteDescription, imgurl;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            // Connect to website
            Document document = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
            // Get the html document title
            websiteTitle = document.title();




            //Here It's just print whole property of URL
            Elements metaElems = document.select("meta");
            for (Element metaElem : metaElems) {
                String property = metaElem.attr("property");
                Log.e("Property", "Property =" + property + " \n Value =" + metaElem.attr("content"));
            }


            // Locate the content attribute
            websiteDescription = metaElems.attr("content");
            String ogImage = null;
            Elements metaOgImage = document.select("meta[property=og:image]");
            if (metaOgImage != null) {
                imgurl = metaOgImage.first().attr("content");
                System.out.println("src :<<<------>>> " + ogImage);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        text.setText("Title : " + websiteTitle + "\n\nImage Url :: " + imgurl);

        //t2.setText(websiteDescription);
        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(imgurl).into(imgOgImage);

    }

}
```

}

**Note :** Here I have just roughly making this demo.no any coding standard will user so please take care this while you ingrate this code in your application.I am just making this demo for learning purpose only.

Here I am just used youtube url for display meta data.you can used any url based on your requirement.

I hope you are clear with my logic.

**Good Luck**